# asp.net button doesn't cause post back when clicked repeatedly

Tags: asp.net, button, click, postback

If I click a button very fast after page load, the post back won't be fired. The following example illustrates this (you have to click the button twice and very fast):

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <span id="submitText"></span>
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="btnSubmitTest" runat="server" Text="Button" 
        OnClientClick="document.getElementById('submitText').innerText='you should not see this after postback';"  />
    </div>
</form>
```

The submitText, the button set's before firing, should not be visible after the postback. But if you click at the button very fast, it happens, that the event doesn't fire.

I think, that the page isn't loaded completely at this moment. Or is there any other reason for that behaviour? How do you handle this?

Comment: One solution would be to disable the button and enable it in $(document).ready. At that point, the DOM is completly loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You will loose all javascript dom updates on postback. What you have explained sounds correct... you see the client click event fire *just* before page posts back and the dom is reset.

Try the same exercise by populating a textbox.  In that instance the value will maintain as the textbox relies on viewstate.  You could put a runat="server" on the span, but I believe you would have to manually assign the value to viewstate as I don't believe htmlgenericcontrols automatically utilize viewstate.